# validating data migration in Sql server 2005

Tags: t-sql

I am migrating data from non-unicode database table to unicode database table.
We have around 40 tables and need to do at least row count validation on migrated data.

Writing the same code repetitively to validate all the tables seems a wrong way.

So whats the correct way of validating data migration.

I am using T-SQL and looking for some code samples for doing row count check.

Answer (score 0):

This query will compare tables in two databases and return those where number of rows is different or the table is missing in one of the databases. Replace `AAA` and `BBB` with database names in your system.

```
SELECT 
    DbB.Name DbBName, DbA.Rows DbARows, DbB.Rows DbBRows
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.rows Rows, tbl.name Name
    FROM  AAA.sys.tables AS tbl INNER JOIN AAA.sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id = tbl.object_id
    ) DbA
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.rows Rows, tbl.name Name
    FROM  BBB.sys.tables AS tbl INNER JOIN BBB.sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id = tbl.object_id
    ) DbB ON DbA.Name = DbB.Name
WHERE
    DbA.Rows <> DbB.Rows OR DbA.Rows IS NULL OR DbB.Rows IS NULL
```

If databases are on different server, create `Linked Server` and use fully qualified table names.